# Is recapitulation theory correct?

Tags: evolution

Most school books still say that recapitulation is an evidence of evolution but as far as I know it has been proved wrong so why is it being still taught? Has it got any sort of relevance?

Comment: **It is not correct and is outdated.** However, it is a compelling hypothesis and was formulated based on interesting pieces of evidence. It has been discussed on this SE before, please use the search function. See e.g. [this answer of mine, and the rest of the thread](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/81642/43353) or [this excellent article from 30 odd years ago](https://academic.oup.com/sysbio/article/27/3/348/1640354).

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. Your question has a couple of problems. First, you should explain breifly what recapitulation is. I don't know. Then you should cite an actual modern text book that still presents it. Then you should explain the basis that it is thought to be incorrect so that your question is about a clear and specific biological idea, that can be answered objectively. Don't ask questions in terms of "why it is being taught" — an answer may well be out of the realms of biology. Ask, instead, whether a scientific argument against the idea is correct.